# Streamline plot of cylinder

Tags: matlab

I have made this plot of streamlines around a cylinder with a radius of 1. Is there a way to remove whats inside the cylinder and maybe even high lite the cylinder with a different colour?

[image]

```
 clear
    % make axes
    xymax = 2;
    x = linspace(-xymax,xymax,100);
    y = linspace(-xymax,xymax,100);
    % note that x and y don't include 0
    [X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
    R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2);
    sin_th = Y./R;
    cos_th = X./R;
    U = 1;
    a = 1;
    psi = U*(R - a*a./R).*sin_th;
    figure
    contour(X,Y,psi,[-3:.25:3],'-b');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mask what you don't want to draw with `nan`:

```
psi((Y>0 & psi<0) | (Y<0 & psi>0)) = nan;
```

and than [draw a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL0hm.png) on it:

```
rectangle('Position', [-1 -1 2 2],'Curvature',[1 1],'EdgeColor','r')
```

Here is the code and result:

```
% make axes
xymax = 2;
x = linspace(-xymax,xymax,100);
y = linspace(-xymax,xymax,100);
% note that x and y don't include 0
% [X,Y] = meshgrid(x(x<-1 | x>1),y(y<-1 | y>1));
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2);
sin_th = Y./R;
cos_th = X./R;
U = 1;
a = 1;
psi = U*(R - a*a./R).*sin_th;
% mask the inner part with nans:
psi((Y>0 & psi<0) | (Y<0 & psi>0)) = nan;
contour(X,Y,psi,[-3:0.25:3],'-b');
% draw a circle:
rectangle('Position', [-1 -1 2 2],'Curvature',[1 1],'EdgeColor','r')
axis equal
```

[image: red circle]

---

You can try also changing directly `X` and `Y` (instead of `Y` and `psi`):

```
psi(Y>-1 & X>-1 & Y<1 & X<1) = nan;
```

but the result is a bit different.

[image: red circle 2]

Comment: You won't need to mask if you set the circle's (rectangle's) 'FaceColor' property.

Answer (score 1):

This is counter-intuitive, but the `rectangle` function can be used to draw a circle!

```
hold on
rectangle('Position',[-R,-R,2*R,2*R],'Curvature',[1,1],'FaceColor',[1 1 0])
```

Feel free to play around with the line properties too ('EdgeColor' and 'LineWidth')

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html